# React Tip functionality

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Newbie question... :) I'm trying to show and hide a tip on a element after a click. It now works on the initial click to open the element but I would like to toggle the state after the initial click. And in the opened element also would like to use a element to close the content again...any help is highly appreciated!

````
const Tip = () => {
   const [showResults, showTipContent] = React.useState(false)
   const onClick = () => showTipContent(true)
   return (
     <span onClick={onClick}>
       <svg className="cursor-pointer" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
         <path d="M12 9.5C12.6904 9.5 13.25 8.9404 13.25 8.25C13.25 7.5596 12.6904 7 12 7C11.3096 7 10.75 7.5596 10.75 8.25C10.75 8.9404 11.3096 9.5 12 9.5ZM11 11V17H13V11H11Z" fill="#111111"/>
         <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M12 2C6.4771 2 2 6.4771 2 12C2 17.5228 6.4771 22 12 22C17.5228 22 22 17.5228 22 12C22 6.4771 17.5228 2 12 2ZM4 12C4 7.5817 7.5817 4 12 4C16.4183 4 20 7.5817 20 12C20 16.4183 16.4183 20 12 20C7.5817 20 4 16.4183 4 12Z" fill="#111111"/>
       </svg>
       { showResults ? <TipContent /> : null }
     </span>
   )
 }
 const TipContent = () => (
   <div className="tipContent">
     {tip}
     <span className="cursor-pointer">CLOSE</span>
   </div>
 )```
````

Comment: Have a click handler that hides it? Or a handler that takes a boolean?

Comment: You need to pass the showTipContent function down to the TipContent component.
As a rule of thumb, your state hook variables should have standard names - for example: [showing. setShowing]. In your case, [showResults, setShowResults]. Just FYI.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to enable toggle functionality so that your button shows and also hides your content. If so you'll want to change your `onClick` to toggle your `showResults` state rather than always having it hardcoded to `true`. You can toggle a boolean value by using `!` ([logical not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_NOT)) in front of it.

In order to enable your child component to close your content, you can pass through your toggle function as a [prop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Client-side_JavaScript_frameworks/React_getting_started#component_props) to it. The function that youu pass can be the same one that you use to toggle your `showResults` state, as the "close" button will only appear if the `Tip` is open, making it set your state to `showResults` to false (ie: which will hide the component):

```js
const Tip = () => {
   const [showResults, showTipContent] = React.useState(false)
   const toggleResults = () => showTipContent(results => !results); // toggle the current state value from hidden to visible, and visible to hidden
   
   return (
     <span onClick={toggleResults}>
       <svg className="cursor-pointer" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
         <path d="M12 9.5C12.6904 9.5 13.25 8.9404 13.25 8.25C13.25 7.5596 12.6904 7 12 7C11.3096 7 10.75 7.5596 10.75 8.25C10.75 8.9404 11.3096 9.5 12 9.5ZM11 11V17H13V11H11Z" fill="#111111"/>
         <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M12 2C6.4771 2 2 6.4771 2 12C2 17.5228 6.4771 22 12 22C17.5228 22 22 17.5228 22 12C22 6.4771 17.5228 2 12 2ZM4 12C4 7.5817 7.5817 4 12 4C16.4183 4 20 7.5817 20 12C20 16.4183 16.4183 20 12 20C7.5817 20 4 16.4183 4 12Z" fill="#111111"/>
       </svg>
       { showResults ? <TipContent closeContent={toggleResults}/> : null }
     </span>
   )
 }
 const TipContent = ({closeContent}) => (
   <div className="tipContent">
     {tip}
     <span className="cursor-pointer" onClick={closeContent}>CLOSE</span>
   </div>
 )
```

Comment: @KnapLelijk no worries, just realized you can remove the `closeContent` function from the parent, as the `toggleResults()` function can also be used instead to set the state of `showResults` to `false` (I've updated my answer with these changes)